# ASP.NET MVC: view does not function well for file upload

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add *upload a file* field inside my Views.
I edited my ViewModel and added below line to it:
        public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUrl { get; set; }
Then I added below helper for file upload:

```
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
```

I also changed my form helper like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

However it shows internal fields of file when I run my view:

[image]

What I have missed that lead to this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TextBoxFor` helper method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
                                          new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.ImageUrl,new { type="file"})
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Or even pure HTML

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
                                                 new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
   <input type="file" name="ImageUrl" />
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this will return null in my ViewModel? my httppost controller looks like this  `public ActionResult Create(ViewModelCreate viewModel)` and viewModel.ImageUrl is null.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ImageUrl property on your model object looks as follows:

```
[DataType(DataType.Upload)]
public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUrl { get; set; }
```

And then, in your view, just use the editorfor HTML helper as per normal

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ImageUrl)
```