# Upload Images while creating new Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm going to create profile for my users in ASP.Net MVC application. Users creation controller is something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(UserProfileViewModel userViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ....
    }

    return View(userViewModel);
}
```

Besides, each user model got several properties including one photo. Everything goes well till I want to add an input field to accept photo.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageUrl, new { type = "file" })
```

And I add below field to `UserProfileViewModel`:

```
[Display(Name = "Profile Photo")]
public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUrl { get; set; }
```

Among snippets to upload a photo and answers to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102093/asp-net-mvc-view-does-not-function-well-for-file-upload), it seems uploading photo was considered as a separate task. i.e. I need an individual form and controller to upload a photo ([like first part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16256106/1080355)).

I want to know are there any methods that I can create whole user profile in one form and pass its photo to the same controller (which included photo in `UserProfileViewModel`)?

I need to note I don't know to use jQuery or AJAX and I want to use standard HTML helpers for this task.

*Update:* My View Looks like this:

```
@model ProjectManager.Models.UserProfileViewModel 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>User Profile</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUrl, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageUrl, new { type = "file" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="ثبت" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div class="rtl text-right">
    @Html.ActionLink("Back To List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: how your view part looks like

Comment: So what problems are you having?

Comment: @StephenMuecke currently file is not posted to ViewModel and ImageURL is null on httppost.

Comment: Then show your view - have you includedthe `enctype` attribute in the `<form>` tag?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated my answer

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I added view part

Comment: You need to use an overload of `BeginForm()` that allows you to add htmlAttributes, and because you need to add `new {enctype = "multipart/form-data" }` if you want to upload files. - e.g. `@using (Html.BeginForm("UserProfileViewModel ", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've tried this already, but my mistake was to write it as `Html.BeginForm("Create", "UserController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }` and I faced with `HTTP Not Found` error. The porblem was about `UserController` which must be `User` and I should not include controller based on conventions.

Comment: @StephenMuecke please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File inputs are not sent in the request unless your form element contains the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` attribute. Change the view code to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All i have got, your question is `I want to know are there any methods that I can create whole user profile in one form and pass its photo to the same controller (which included photo in UserProfileViewModel)?`

Yes. It is possible. If you overwrite the form as `Stephen Muecke` said, you should get the photo with viewmodel. If you get null in viewmodel, you can retrieve the file(photo) from the request also.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(UserProfileViewModel userViewModel)
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      HttpPostedFileBase fileUploadObj= Request.Files[0];
      //for collection
      HttpFileCollectionBase fileUploadObj= Request.Files;
    ....
   }

   return View(userViewModel);
  }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: OP already has a property in the model for the file! - this has nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use an BeginForm() that allows you to add htmlAttributes, and because you need to add 
new {enctype = "multipart/form-data" }

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserProfileViewModel ", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UserProfileViewModel(UserProfileViewModel userViewModel)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload= Request.Files[0];
  //for collection
  HttpFileCollectionBase fileUpload= Request.Files;
 ....
 }
```